# Can't get <mvc:resources> working in Spring 3

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Trying to link a css stylesheet to one of my jsp files, but I seem to be missing something because the stylesheet is never found.

mvc-config.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

my link tag in jsp file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/testing/resources/css/common.css">
```

web.xml:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
                /WEB-INF/datasource.xml,
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
                /WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml
        </param-value>
  </context-param>

    <!--  Spring Security Filter -->
    <filter>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

My folder structure is webapp/resources/css

What am I missing? 
When I try to access the css file directly through the browser, it just redirects me to my jsp file.

Comment: Looks ok from first glance. I would expect a 404 instead of a redirect when accessing the css directly, however, if something was misconfigured. Do you have any re-directs in your Controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you are including a security configuration file in your web.xml. Make sure you disable security for your assets / resources:

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
```